# Temporarily disable distributed processing in celery

Tags: python, celery

I want to temporarily convert the distributed behavior of a celery `task` to serial behavior. That is to say, I want the process to run the task code as if the `task` decorator were not present. I need this for debugging purposes.

I could swear there was an env var which handles this but I can't seem to find it in the documentation?

For example:

```
@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

When the `add_together` method is called I do not want it sent to a celery worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean eager mode which can be turned on with [`task_always_eager`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager) setting. With that turned on, all tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the queue.